# Finding the density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, bivariate-distributions

I have this problem
Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables that have a joint density function given by,

Find the density function of $X - Y$.

My problem is, that I don´t how to choose the integrals intervals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{y}^{y+z}8(y+z)y\,dy\,dz$$

Is this statement correct?

Comment: No.  Your inner integral has *both* $y$ and $z$ mentioned in its bounds, so that is clearly erroneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do a drawing.
Then realize that

$$F_Z(z)=\int_{0}^{1+z} 8x dx \int_{x-z}^{1}y dy$$

This because:

1. $z \in [-1;0]$
2. Using the CDF method you get

$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}[X-Y \leq z]=\mathbb{P}[Y \geq X-z]$$

Then the area to be integrated is the purple one, as shown in the following picture

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for your help. Could you tell me why doesn´t FZ(z)  have an expression like this one  fX,Y(ξ,ξ−a)dξ

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly note that the support $0\leq X\lt Y\leq 1$, means $-1\leq X{-}Y\lt 0,$ and $-(X{-}Y)\lt Y\leq 1$.

Then we just use the Jacobian transformation, to find the joint pdf, and integrate this to find the required marginal.

$$\begin{align}f_{\small X-Y,Y}(z,y)&=\begin{Vmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{Vmatrix}~f_{\small X,Y}(z+y,y)\\[1ex]&=8(z+y)y~\mathbf 1_{\small 0\leq z+y\lt y\leq 1}\\[1ex]&=8(z+y)y~\mathbf 1_{\small 0\lt -z\leq y\leq 1}\\[4ex]f_{\small X-Y}(z)&={8\int_\Bbb R (z+y)y~\mathbf 1_{\small 0\lt -z\leq y\leq 1}~\mathrm d y}\\[1ex]&={8~\mathbf 1_{\small -1\leq z\lt 0}\cdot\int_{-z}^1 (z+y)y~\mathrm d y}\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks, but I have doubts already, I just want to understand better.  Sorry It´s a little bit confusing for me :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are integrating over a triangle given by points $(x, y)=(0, 0)$, $(0, 1)$, and $(1, 1)$. Your solution should cover the whole region to be correct.

Then consider that the probability that $X-Y$ equals a given quantity $a$ as lines intersecting the triangle with slope 1 and $x$-intercept of $a$.

Then the integrated probability that $X$ and $Y$ lie on that line would be the following integral

$$
P(X-Y=a)=\int_{a}^{1} f_{X,Y}(\xi, \xi-a)d\xi
$$

Here $\xi$ is a variable of integration which represents the $x$ coordinate on the prescribed line. With $a$ taking values from 0 to 1 the whole region is covered.

Comment: Thanks for your help, could u show me how can I express  fX,Y(ξ,a−ξ)dξ, this part, this is to know if what I am thinking is correct

Comment: Because the integral is only placed on the region where the function is nonzero then $f_{X,Y}(\xi, a-\xi)=8\xi(a-\xi)$

Comment: I'm sorry, i misread your original question, I need to edit my response